# Is it possible to insert a file in SQL server by using classic asp?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm using SQL server 2008 and here we have to maintain a legacy application written in classic ASP. Now I have to keep some files inside the application and I'm wondering if is possible to do that by insert it in some SQL server database. Can anybody tell me if is possible? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to store entire files in SQL Server as BLOBs (large binary objects).  Be advised that depending on the number of files and the size of those files, SQL Server's data and log files may get very large is you are using this approach.

You may want to look at using SQL Server's FILESTREAM capabilities:  There is a good overview on Microsoft TechNet @ [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)